# masonry not adjusting to jQuery set hidden

Tags: jquery, load, jquery-masonry

I'm using masonry (jQuery plugin) to create ["fluid" awesome columns](http://masonry.desandro.com/).
Everything worked great until I added a field that is visible if javascript is turned off, otherwise when the page is loaded I hide the fields and show a "read more" link (läs mer)...

But Masonry takes the hidden field into account when it sets the positions of the divs =/

any ideas?

You can see it here: http://hyrakontorsplats.nu/

Update:
I tried to move the call for masonry last, and that did the trick for loading.. 
but now it doesn't reorder the way it should when I click read more and show the element.

$('.merInfo').hide();
    $('.lasMer').show();

```
$('#kontorsplatser').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.kontorsplats',
  //isRTL: true  //align right :)
});
```

Comment: For this kind of stuff, you may want to check out the big brother of Masonry which is called Isotope. There, you can easily filter, sort and order large amounts of content, typical for fastighetsmäklare and that kind of företag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

Look for reload here: http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/methods.html
My final (working!) code:

$('.merInfo').hide();
    $('.lasMer').show();

```
$(".lasMer").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings(".merInfo").show();
    $(this).hide();
    $('#kontorsplatser').masonry( 'reload' );

});

$('#kontorsplatser').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.kontorsplats',
  //isRTL: true  //align right :)
});
```

Comment: thank you I tried doing it by interchanging two css classes one for hidden and one for visible which caused my items to end up overlapping(although they were rearranged a bit) but your solution works!